# Android error: Use *#9900# to take log

Tags: android

i'm facing an interesting problem. My android application is running fine on Samsung Galaxy SII or HTC Desire, but running it on Samsung Galaxy Pocket is quite a problem. I was told, that everytime it was started, after few minutes it showed this:

Sorry! - Use *#9900# to take log - application was unexpectedly closed, try again.

I can't find satisfying answer about what could be causing this, so i would appreciate any help!
Thanks, Mike.

Comment: What you are seeing is the standard Force Close dialog an Android application incurs when a fatal exception is thrown.  The wording has been customized by Samsung, but it still boils down to the fact that you need the stack trace from logcat to truly know what the problem was.  Since it sounds like you don't have one, perhaps ask someone with the device to try that key combination and see if the log data presents itself.

Comment: Please post adb logs to investigate the issue

Comment: Thanks for your advices, now i know, that it doesn't have to be some kind of special error, it just says to check the log (by typing *#9900#). I've also found one really good app for checking log while the device is not plugged in computer and it looks just like the log in eclipse. So i find out, it's just common unhandled null pointer exception.

Comment: Note that incremental log collection apps will not work on more recent Android releases, unless the device "rooted" or otherwise modified to work around the security changes that prevent this.  (It may still be possible to grab crash logs written to storage by the OS - haven't checked that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message was odd, but it was simply unhandled null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can gather is usually a memory problem, cache maybe. You might find your galaxy or desire has a bit more memory or handles cache, ram, etc differently. Try and clean up the system, reset or restart and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and my laptop detected that my phone is missing a driver that is why it is not working properly so downloading that missing driver will solve your problem.

Comment: This should be a comment.